# Quasar Framework (Vue) : Collapsible and mouseleave

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, quasar-framework

I'm trying to figure out a collapsible component inside the [quasar](https://quasar-framework.org/components/collapsible.html#Vue-Events).
For some reason, the mouse hover event does not work.

Please tell me how you can replace the text output area with a button when the user hovers the pointer over .

Please help! :)

```
<q-collapsible 
      opened
      icon="bookmark"
      :label="$t('Custom dashboards')"
      @mouseleave="var2 = true" //It doesn't work :(
      @mouseenter="var2 = false" //It doesn't work
    >
      <q-item>
        <q-btn
          @click="func()"
          icon="add"
          :label="$t('Create')"/>
      </q-item>
      </q-collapsible>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiTwv.png)

Comment: It tries to assign to `var2` in unknown scope.

Comment: The variable exists. It is created in <script > tags.

This variable was needed for v-if (vue.js) operation. But not earned.

Comment: Just avoid global variables or access them as `window.var2`. Also, writing to variable will not trigger redrawing of text.

Comment: Thanks for reply!
But I have a problem in another: the mouse event does not work on the Collapsible

Answer (score 0):

Complete HTML/Script/CSS would be expected to solve your issue. Since that is not available, I basically what you did, but expanded to solve what was supplied in the image.

@mouseleave and @mouseenter are working correctly. You just have to set and use the value to hide/show the button.

I do not believe QCollapsible support a slot in the header (correct be if I am wrong), so it might be better to use a QToolbar in conjunction with QCollapsible and QList.

```js
// Update the variables to toggle the display

new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      listOpen: true,
      hover: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleList: function() {
      this.listOpen = !this.listOpen
    },
    addItem: function() {
      this.$q.notify('clicked')
    }
  },
  computed: {
    hovering() {
      return this.listOpen && this.hover
    }
  }
})
```

```css
// Hide the existing collapse button (maybe there is a property for this)
div.q-collapsible.q-item-division.relative-position.q-collapsible-cursor-pointer>div>div.q-item.q-item-division.relative-position {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<!-- Create a div with the hoverover events -->
<div style="width:500px" @mouseleave="hover = false" @mouseenter="hover = true">
  <q-toolbar>
    <div class="on-left">
      <q-icon name="bookmark">
        <q-icon>
    </div>
    <q-toolbar-title v-show="!hovering">
      Custom Dashboard
    </q-toolbar-title>
    <q-btn v-show="hovering" icon="add" label="Create" class="full-width" @click="addItem"></q-btn>
    <q-btn flat icon="menu" @click="toggleList"></q-btn>
  </q-toolbar>
  <q-collapsible opened v-model="listOpen">
    <div slot="side">test</div>
    <q-list>
      <q-item>
        <q-item-side left>
          <q-icon name="dashboard">
            <q-icon>
        </q-item-side>
        <q-item-main>
          dash 2
        </q-item-main>
      </q-item>
      <q-item>
        <q-item-side left>
          <q-icon name="dashboard">
            <q-icon>
        </q-item-side>
        <q-item-main>
          dash 5
        </q-item-main>
      </q-item>
    </q-list>
  </q-collapsible>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/stevebor1/pen/OroLaL)